# Prove that $\nabla_{A} (XAY) = Y^{T}X^{T}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Equation (3) in Dawen Liang's [Some Important Properties for Matrix Calculus](http://dawenl.github.io/files/mat_deriv.pdf) is

$$\nabla_{A} (XAY) = Y^{T}X^{T}$$

If you know how this can be derived, then please let me know. Thank you.

---

Replying To H. H. Rugh

Thanks for the reply, May I explain my derivative? Let suppose, $$ X\in \Re^{m\times n} A\in \Re^{n\times o} Y\in \Re^{o\times p} $$ and $$\widetilde { x } _{ i }^{T}$$ is an ith row vector of matrix X and $$y_{j} $$ is a ith coulmn vector of Y then I guess I can get a derivative of a component of matrix $(XAY)_{ij} $ like this $$\frac { \partial (XAY)_{ ij } }{ \partial A } =\frac { \partial \widetilde { x }_{ i }^{T} Ay_{ j } }{ \partial A } =\widetilde { x }_{ i}  y_{ j }^{ T }\in \Re ^{ n\times o } $$ So filnally I made a conclusion like $$\frac { \partial XAY }{ \partial A } =\begin{bmatrix} \widetilde { x } _{ 1 }y_{ 1 }^{ T } & \widetilde { x } _{ 2 }y_{ 1 }^{ T } & \cdots  & \widetilde { x } _{ m }y_{ 1 }^{ T } \\ \widetilde { x } _{ 1 }y_{ 2 }^{ T } & \widetilde { x } _{ 2 }y_{ 2 }^{ T } & \cdots  & \widetilde { x } _{ m }y_{ 2 }^{ T } \\ \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ \widetilde { x } _{ 1 }y_{ p }^{ T } & \widetilde { x } _{ 2 }y_{ p }^{ T } & \cdots  & \widetilde { x } _{ m }y_{ p }^{ T } \end{bmatrix}\in \Re ^{ pn\times mo }$$ by denominator layout notation. Is my derivation wrong?
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives

The reason why I have been asking this is I guess there might be a typo in eq.(3). But I have no confidence. Because I'm not familiar with matrix calculus. So If you have the correct and a detail derivation, and please give that, It would be very helpful to me or if you give an information of documents, which include the derivation, it also good to me. I spend all day to find the derivation of eq.(3) yesterday. Because I guess, if the eq.(3) is one of the basic properties, then many documents may include it, but I couldn't find it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is wrong and the result should be $X^T Y^T$ (reverse order). Although the cited text uses square matrices for this case, it should also hold for non-square matrices of size, say $m\times n$. Taking the gradient of a scalar with respect to $A$ should yield a matrix of the same size, which is consistent with the definition on the first page of the cited text (and not the claimed result).

For the $(k,l)$'th element you have (summation on repeated indices):
$$ \left( \nabla_A (X A Y) \right)_{k,l} = \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{k,l}} X_i A_{ij} Y_j = X_i \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} Y_l = X_k Y_l = \left(X^T Y^T\right)_{k,l} $$

Comment: Thank you H.H. Rugh, But I still don't understand meaning of $$ \frac {\partial}{\partial A_{k,l}} X_{i}A_{ij}Y_{j} $$ because I have been guessed $$ \nabla_{A}(XAY))_{k,l}= \frac {\partial}{\partial A_{k,l}} XAY $$ might be correct. Also I don't know why the Kronecker delta function is used for. Could you give a reference to understand it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a reference, but for example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  \sum_j x_j^2 = \sum_j 2 x_j \delta_{i,j} = 2 x_i$. The same if you have two indices. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: And I have 2 more questions What's the meaning of $X_{i}$ and $Y_{j}$

Comment: I see your point, also in your new edit. Indeed in my derivation I presumed $X$ and $Y$ are just row and column vectors, respectively. When this is not the case the derivative in the expression (3) in the cited text is in fact a tensor with four indexes which you may write as in your conclusion. The expression (3) [apart from $X$ and $Y$ being in the wrong order] does not quite make sense, at least it should be stated what that sense is. Your conclusion seems ok to me but may be more clear in a given context.

Comment: Thank you, H.H Rugh. I sent a mail to the writer and I'm waiting for his reply. There could be 2 theories. The one is those are vectors, which should have used small and bold characters and missed transpose superscript and something wrong with the order. The second is that he dropped trace operator on the left side in eq.(3). See the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities. I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can prove that:
$$
\nabla_A \mathrm{tr}(AX)=X^T.
$$
You can simply prove that by direct calculation (or by using the linearity of differentiation and finding the derivative only for a matrix $X$ all zero except $x_{ij}$).

Then using this and properties of trace we have:
$$
\nabla_A(XAY)=\nabla_A\mathrm{tr}(XAY)=\nabla_A\mathrm{tr}(AYX)=(YX)^T=X^TY^T.
$$

Comment: Thank you Arash, But I still want to know the property $$ \nabla_{A}(XAY) = \nabla_{A}tr(XAY)  $$. If you have a reference to understand, please give the site to me. Thanks

Comment: I guess if the $$XAY$$ is a scalar value, then the above could be correct but $$XAY$$ seems to be a matrix, in case of that, Is the property still valid?

Comment: Because usually a capital character is used to be a matrix, not a vector, and if the notation is correct and  $X$ is a vector, I guess it shout be $X^{T}$ because normally the vector is column vector, not row vector

Comment: Note that if $XAY$ is a general matrix of dimension more than $1\times 1$, its gradient will be a tensor and your result is not correct.  So I assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are matrices of dimension $1\times m$ and $n\times 1$.

Comment: Ok, Your opinion is based on the scalar by matrix like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix then you are correct. But I would like to say again, I haven't experienced the mixed expression like  $X$ is a low vector and $Y$ is a column vector ever. If the writer intended it then it could be a mistake.

Comment: And you mentioned the tensor, So Can you give the results of the matrix by matrix derivative?

Answer (score 0):

Expressed in index notation (and the summation convention), your function is
$$F_{il} = X_{ij}A_{jk}Y_{kl}$$
The differential is simply
$$dF_{il} = X_{ij}\,dA_{jk}\,Y_{kl}$$
So, assuming that $A$ has no special structure, the gradient is 
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial F_{il}}{\partial A_{ps}}
 &= X_{ij}(\delta_{jp}\delta_{ks})Y_{kl} \cr
 &= X_{ip} Y_{sl} \cr
}$$
Not sure how to write this result using standard matrix operations.

Comment: Thank you, lynn. But I think there is not only one matrix element $X_{ij}$ $Y_{kl}$ which is involved with the derivative by $\partial A_{ps}$ The involved things in the derivative by  $\partial A_{ps}$ are a column vector in $X$ and a row vector in $Y$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:A\in M_{n,o}\rightarrow XAY\in M_{m,p}$; $f$ has its values in $\mathbb{R}^{mp}$ (and not in $\mathbb{R}$). Thus $f$ admits $mp$ gradient-vectors; more precisely, $\nabla(f)(A)$ is a tensor defined by the $\nabla(f_{i,j})(A)$ when $(i\le m,j\leq p)$ varies.

$f_{i,j}(A)=(XAY)_{i,j}=e_i^TXAYe_j=tr(e_i^TXAYe_j)=tr(Ye_je_i^TXA)=tr(YE_{j,i}XA)=<(YE_{j,i}X)^T,A>$, where $<.>$ is the standard scalar product.

By duality, $\nabla(f_{i,j})(A)=(YE_{j,i}X)^T=X^TE_{i,j}Y^T$.

Comment: Thank you lop blanc for your reply. I have some questions. [1] Is the $e_{i}$ a column vector, the ith component of which is only 1, and the rest are 0?  [2] If [1] is correct, then don't you think $X^{T}E_{i,j}Y_{T}= \tilde { x } _{ i }y_{ j }^{ T }$ ?  [3] Could you give a reference to know the relation $tr(BA)=<(B)^{T},A>$  I'm not familiar with the standard scalar product of matrix

Comment: [1] yes. [2] yes. [3] The gradient is defined with the help of the following inner product:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask one more question? I'm trying to understand tensor from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor. but I'm not sure if the 'tensor' in the wiki is same with mentioned 'tensor' by you. Because it apparently has no relation to the contents in wiki. Is it same with? And Is there any reference, which could give a more correlated definition of tensor  with mentioned it by you?